# Apply for each loop to AI builder Model

Tags: power-automate

I have created Model with  AI builder custom models to read data from PDF and add that data to Excel spreadsheet stored in SharePoint. In Power Automate, flow should be Manual Trigger -> Get PDF files (nearly 1000) from Sharepoint folder -> Extract data from each PDF and write to excel (AI) using I guess Apply to each.

I can get to All files successfully but Apply to each not working. Need help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ask yourself this question, if you were trying to answer this question, would you be able to help with the lack of information you’ve provided? Where’s (at a minimum) an image of your flow? Did you get any errors? If so, what and where are they occurring?

Comment: Added images. The step at Document Processing is failing.

Comment: Got an error or something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.